# Stripe Payments Linking my own database table to a customer ID on Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am hoping someone can help me here.

I am trying to process subcription payments through stripe I have code that redirects you to the checkout once a button is clicked:

```
<script>
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_CJ3p2EuKzHOC0mQrx9AIDZ3R00TR4ysmyS');

    document.getElementById("checkout-button").addEventListener('click', function () {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items: [{
          // Define the product and plan in the Dashboard first, and use the plan
          // ID in your client-side code.
          plan: 'plan_Fd6dQD8JT0sl0C',
          quantity: 1,

        }],
        successUrl: 'https://www.example.com/success',
        cancelUrl: 'https://www.example.com/cancel'
      });
    });
</script>
```

I then have set up a webhook to do some processing once this has completed:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("TEST KEY");
// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);
// for extra security, retrieve from the Stripe API
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_id);
// This will send receipts on succesful invoices


if ($event->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
    include 'email_template_functions/email_function.php';
    include 'email_template_functions/password_reset_email_templatetest.php';

    sendemail('triggertraders.com','richard@triggertraders.com','Bluebanana1995',465,'richard@triggertraders.com', 'Richard','rglass5565@gmail.com','richard@triggertraders.com',
    'Information','Reset Password Trigger Trader','This has worked!!','This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients');
}
```

So this works fine and the payments are going through to stripe its the next step I am wondering about.

I have a entity table in my database that contains all of the 'client' data which has an entity_id.  I am trying to figure out a way to link the stripe customer_id to my entity_id in my local database so I can update their account when a payment is made but I cant see how I can do this.

Is there some way I can send my own entity_id to stripe when a payment is set up so when I retrive that data from the webhook and can update my database correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-redirect-to-checkout it makes reference to clientReferenceId which I can use to store the ID that i need.

```
<script>
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_CJ3p2EuKzHOC0mQrx9AIDZ3R00TR4ysmyS');

    document.getElementById("checkout-button").addEventListener('click', function () {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items: [{
          // Define the product and plan in the Dashboard first, and use the plan
          // ID in your client-side code.
          plan: 'plan_Fd6dQD8JT0sl0C',
          quantity: 1,



        }],
        clientReferenceId: '123',
        successUrl: 'https://www.example.com/success',
        cancelUrl: 'https://www.example.com/cancel'
      });
    });
</script>
```

I then can use this in my webhook - anybody know of any other ways to do this?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but you can use the metadata field https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata